# Automated UITableVIew Cell swiped (edit)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to make a UITableView cell load with is swiped right to show the presence of the editing functions. I would like to do it as a way to educate the uses in my app that it can be done in one of the tableViews with that function.

e.g. I have attached a screen short of the mail app with a cell swiped and would like my app to load with a cell swiped like that already.

[image]

Thanks in advance. ;)

The Swift conversion of the AnimateCell ObjectiveC Answer below

var cell : UITableViewCell?

func animateCell() {

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 2, section: 1)



cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath) as IndexPath)

//  The crash occurs here with lldb
var aLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (cell?.bounds.size.width)!, y: 0, width: 200, height: (cell?.bounds.height)!))
aLabel.text! = "Delete"
aLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
aLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
cell?.addSubview(aLabel)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {() -> Void in
    self.cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (self.cell?.frame.origin.x)! - 100, y: (self.cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (self.cell?.bounds.size.width)!, height: (self.cell?.bounds.size.height)!)

    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {() -> Void in

            self.cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (self.cell?.frame.origin.x)! + 100, y: (self.cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (self.cell?.bounds.size.width)!, height: (self.cell?.bounds.size.height)!)

            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
                aLabel.removeFromSuperview()
                aLabel = nil
        })
})
```

}

Comment: There are not many concrete links online. I know how to build the editing process to help a user swipe and delete a cell and it's data. But there are no clear ways on how automate it. My current method is to use a custom popup to tell the user about the capability.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
-(void)animateCell{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    __block UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width,
                                                                           0,
                                                                           200,
                                                                           cell.bounds.size.height)];

    aLabel.text = @"Delete";
    aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    aLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell addSubview:aLabel];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x - 100, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + 100, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [aLabel removeFromSuperview];
            aLabel = nil;
        }];
    }];

}
```

You can call this method in `viewDidAppear` after a short time..

**UPDATE**

For Swift 3 you can use like reference:

```
func animateCell() {
        var cell : UITableViewCell?
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath) as IndexPath)

        var aLabel : UILabel! = UILabel()
        //aLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        aLabel.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.bounds.size.width)!, y: 0, width: 400, height: (cell?.bounds.height)!)
        cell?.clipsToBounds = false
        print(aLabel.frame)
        aLabel!.text = "Delete"
        aLabel!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        print(aLabel.frame)
        aLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell?.addSubview(aLabel)


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)! - 100, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (cell?.bounds.size.width)!, height: (cell?.bounds.size.height)!)

            }) { (finished: Bool) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)! + 100, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (cell?.bounds.size.width)!, height: (cell?.bounds.size.height)!)

                    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                        aLabel.removeFromSuperview()
                        aLabel = nil
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had rewritten this in swift without much success. I have posted my swift rewrite and commented the point where the crash occurs. Do you mind giving me a tip to what I could do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set default editing mode to tableview. Editing mode is a state of the UITableView. You can set it programmatically with:

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]
```

You can do this with or without animation.

Comment: Unfortunately this method will only show the delete buttons on the left strangely. I certainly thought it would work.